# Show tick on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my JS when a button with `data-complete` is clicked it gives me the value I need via `targetDiv`.

From this I am having issues with the `.complete-tick` class as I would like to add the `.css({'display' : 'block'});` class to it.  How?

**HTML:**

```
 <button class="complete" data-complete="showTick-1" type="button">click me <div class="complete-tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $('[data-complete]').on('click', function(e) {
        var targetDiv = jQuery(this).attr('data-complete');

       (".complete-tick").css({'display' : 'block'});

        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

Comment: Missing `]`. `$('[data-complete')` => `$('[data-complete]')`

Comment: missing `]` in the selector

Comment: `$('.complete').on('click', function(e) {
    var targetDiv = $(this).data('complete');
    $('.' + targetDiv).show();
    e.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery addClass onClick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566838/jquery-addclass-onclick)

Comment: @Tushar Thanks but how can I append my .complete-tick css?  I have multi buttons so my targetDiv is what separates them

Comment: you can add as $('.complete-tick').css('display','block');

Comment: @Geeky but that does not take into account the targetDiv - the whole reason for this code :)

Comment: in your callback function `targetDiv` is not a div, just a string - `'showTick-1'` - is that supposed to be a class, an id, what? you need to include your full html including the element you expect `targetDiv` to refer to for anyone to know what to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add necessary styling for div with class `.complete-tick`. as far as your issue is concerned below code should work.

```js
$(function(){
    $('[data-complete]').on('click', function(e) {
        //var targetDiv = $(this).attr('data-complete');

       $(this).find(".complete-tick").css('display','block');

        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="complete" data-complete="showTick-1" type="button">click me <div class="complete-tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></button>
```

PS: You are missing font-awesome css.

Comment: It still does not use targetDiv - This is needed currently on click all boxes show the tick :)

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `var targetDiv`.?

Comment: I think he will have multiple `button.complete` elements - and just needs to only affect the `.complete-tick` element inside the clicked one - but was kind of going a roundabout way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I added some spare buttons to demonstrate that it works for multiple buttons, and the text 'Tick goes here' as a placeholder (I assume in your actual project you are including the font-awesome files so that an actual tick displays)

Is this what you mean? You don't need to worry about fetching targetDiv if you always just want to target `.complete-tick` inside the clicked button:

```js
$(function(){
    $('[data-complete]').on('click', function(e) {
       $(".complete-tick", this).css('display','block');

        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

```css
.complete-tick {
    display:none;
}
.complete-tick i:before {
    content:'tick goes here';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="complete" data-complete="showTick-1" type="button">click me <div class="complete-tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></button>
<button class="complete" data-complete="showTick-2" type="button">click me <div class="complete-tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></button>
<button class="complete" data-complete="showTick-3" type="button">click me <div class="complete-tick"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></button>
```